# Trigger menu open from a button

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a menu defined in my html:

```
 <md-menu>
 <!-- Trigger element is a md-button with an icon -->
    <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Open sample menu">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="call:phone"></md-icon>
       </md-button>
    <md-menu-content>
        <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button></md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

and a button somewhere else on the same html:

```
<md-button ng-click="openOtherMenu()">Open Menu</md-button>
```

I want that clicking on the Open Menu button will trigger the opening of the menu. I am not sure what needs to be in openOtherMenu(). Any ideas?

Comment: I dont think you can open menu using `md-button` which is define outside of the `md-menu` element.

Answer (score 2):

try
1)assign some id or class

```
  <md-button id='luis' ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)"
```

2) in your controller

```
 .controller('yourcontroller',function($scope,$timeout){

$scope.openOtherMenu=function(){
   $timeout(function(){
     var ele=document.getElementById('luis');
     angular.element(ele).triggerHandler('click');
   },0);
```

}